# Intro to statistics for an MD?

Tags: references

I have a friend who is an MD and wants to refresh his Statistics. So is there any recommended resource online (or offline) ? He did stats ~20 years ago.

Comment: What's the significance of the fact that your friend is an MD?

Comment: I think the significance of the MD is the person in question is a busy clinician, and not a researcher. Therefore we are being guided towards your less weighty tomes as source recommendations. Well, that's from the MD's I come across anyway.

Comment: Exactly! The fact that he is an MD poses a few restriction on (a) the volume of the introductory material (b) on what to assume about the "starting point" and (c) on the time willing to spend to reintroduce himself with basic stuff.

Comment: Is he looking to perform statistical analyses, interpret the output or critique published papers that use statistical methods?

Comment: @Shane The friend being an MD has a fair amount of significance to it - the answers should likely be oriented, for example, more towards statistics used in clinical practice, study design, etc. A reading list involving new and exciting variance estimators for obscure model types...less useful ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is the one I've used successfully:

[Statistics Without Maths for Psychology: Using Spss for Windows](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Statistics-without-Psychology-Christine-Dancey/dp/013124941X).

I just stumbled on this too, this might be useful:

[Statistics Notes in the British Medical Journal](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/%7Emb55/pubs/pbstnote.htm).

I'm sure I knew of a free pdf that some doctors I know use, but I can't seem to find it at the moment. I will try to dig it out.

Comment: I've read the link and "Statistics without psychology", I was like: Wut? Then I opened the book: "Statistics Without Maths for Psychology"

Comment: Lol. Although I fear a "Psychology without statistics" book would be a bestseller...

Answer (score 2):

My book, [*Intuitive Biostatistics*](http://www.intuitivebiostatistics.com), is written partly from a medical point of view. It focusses on the practical parts of interpreting statistical results, with almost no math.

Comment: I work in medical/epidemiological research, and I see this book on colleagues' shelves all the time.  Still haven't read it myself, but I can attest to its popularity.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your friend prefers something that's biostatistics oriented.  Glantz's [Primer of Biostatistics](http://www.powells.com/biblio/62-9780071435093-1) is a small book, an easy and quick read, and tends to get rave reviews from a similar audience.  If an online reference works, I like Gerard Dallal's [Handbook of Statistical Practice](https://web.archive.org/web/20100212183607/http://www.tufts.edu/%7Egdallal/LHSP.HTM), which may do the trick if he's just refreshing previous knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

- **Regression Methods in Biostatistics: Linear, Logistic, Survival, and Repeated Measures Models, Edition 2**
  Eric Vittinghoff · David V. Glidden · Stephen C. Shiboski · Charles E. McCulloch
- **Logistic Regression: A Self-Learning Text (Statistics for Biology and Health) Third (3rd) Edition**
  David G. Kleinbaum, Mitchel Klein
- **Survival Analysis: A Self-Learning Text, Third Edition (Statistics for Biology and Health) 3rd ed. 2012 Edition**
  David G. Kleinbaum, Mitchel Klein
- **Categorical Data Analysis, Second Edition** Alan Agresti

The assumptions here are:

a. As an MD their nose is in the literature all the time, and they are encountering the types of statistics that are typically presented in NEJM, JAMA, Lancet, etc.

b. They are less concerned with actually writing the code and fitting the analysis than of being a high caliber consumer, and potential director of information.