# Concise book/tutorial for Statistics (Data Analysis)

Tags: references, biostatistics, statistical-learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What book would you recommend for non-statistician scientists?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-book-would-you-recommend-for-non-statistician-scientists)

Could anyone suggest a concise book/tutorial on statistics with examples. I am a biologist and need basic concepts with examples.

I have planned 10 days for this learning exercise so please keep that in mind while suggesting.

Thank you

Comment: Related: (**1**) [A resource on concepts underlying statistics, not the techniques used in applied stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7165), (**2**) [What book would you recommend for non-statistician scientists?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421), (**3**) [Teach yourself programming in 10 years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) (*an only slightly tongue-in-cheek suggestion*), (**4**) [Intro to statistics for an MD?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223). There are many other related questions on this site.